# CSS animation for hover effect

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/zn09vjbv/)  set up of the code I have so far.  Basically I can't seem to make the rollover animation happen with hover for the main body of text in each ul.

So when you rollover the individual areas the code for opacity on these classes.....

```
.browser .statistic,
.browser .download {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

Becomes 1.  But i can't seem to get the transition animation to happen  Can someone point me in the right direction.

Cheers,
Greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry if i missunderstanding you.

i just added:

```
li:hover .browser * {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
    transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zn09vjbv/1/

**UPDATE:**

> is there any way to get the "h2 span" class to also change its
>   background position when the li is hover ?

yes, just add this: (add any attribute you like inside this class)

```
li:hover .browser h2 {
    background: #000;
    color; #FFF;
    ......
}
```

Comment: thanks ! is there any way to get the "h2 span" class to also change its background position when the li is hover ?

Comment: @user3504751, glad that i could help, see my last update

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the transition on the main class of the object you are trying to animate, not on the class you are adding on hover

```
.initial-element{
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.initial-element:hover{
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: so in this case it would the class main in that case you think ?

Comment: adding the code to ul li didnt work and stopped the other animation flex working on hover